Proving that LocalStorage Persists after tab close
I've read from internet - that "LocalStorage" data for a tab (persists) and has no expirty date - even after the tab or window is closed.
Case_I: say I go to the website => https://www.hondacarindia.com/
I can see the data in localstorage (Application tab):

I can also run the command to console the data of localstorage:
console.log(localstorage);


yes I can see the same items (8 items here);
Query:
Now if I close the window or tab => I can no longer, have access to (application tab), (console tab); ---> Now is there anyway to know that those 8 items are still there in memory, as tab is gone;
Also:
If I again open website https://www.hondacarindia.com/ (It might be that -- website stores those 8 items again to the new tab) ---> which is 2nd time. There is no way to know that ---> the localStorage data (of 8 items persisted). So, I want to confirm ---> that the 8 items persisted and (they are the old ones, not again in new tab ---> as I browsed the site, added again to my (Application tab).
Can someone help me out, how to confirm that localStorage -> 8 items persisted (when I closed the tab), just proving it?

documentation is all the "proof" you need

You can add a key-value pair into localStorage under the domain https://www.hondacarindia.com/,
close the tab -> open it again to verify if it exists.


How to add a key-value pair in localstorage. Its not my website. Its hondaIndia's? Could you tell me how to do that?

@Deadpool localstorage is saved on your device, it doesn't matter if the website is yours or not. Double click on a new row in "key" column and enter some letters, same goes to "value"

@Deadpool You can also set a new key:value in console: localStorage.setItem("somekey", "somevalue")

Thanks, @LãNgọcHải - Even if I close the tab, or open website -- in new window (data persists) -- it doesn't matter if I add in a tab close it, or later open in new window. My data (as per a website, persists) - If I go to same domain later. <3 proved it.
